# After import sample data 1.9.1.0 can't login admin, no admin user in database?

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento 1.9 with out sample data is work.
then, i installed Magento 1.9 with sample data 1.9.1.0 but didn’t have any admin login. 
i try found admin user in database but it doesn't exist 
can you help me? thank you!

Answer (score 15):

You have to create new admin user and asing that user to proper (Administrators) role. Try to run this

```
LOCK TABLES `admin_role` WRITE , `admin_user` WRITE;

SET @SALT = "rp";
SET @PASS = CONCAT(MD5(CONCAT( @SALT , "password") ), CONCAT(":", @SALT ));
SELECT @EXTRA := MAX(extra) FROM admin_user WHERE extra IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO `admin_user` (firstname,lastname,email,username,password,created,lognum,reload_acl_flag,is_active,extra,rp_token_created_at) 
VALUES ('Firstname','Lastname','email@example.com','myuser',@PASS,NOW(),0,0,1,@EXTRA,NOW());

INSERT INTO `admin_role` (parent_id,tree_level,sort_order,role_type,user_id,role_name) 
VALUES (1,2,0,'U',(SELECT user_id FROM admin_user WHERE username = 'myuser'),'Firstname');

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: I had a banch of unregular text in `extra` column. So, just setting to NULL enabled me to pass to next step. Instead of `# SELECT @EXTRA := MAX(extra) FROM admin_user WHERE extra IS NOT NULL;`, I have `SET @EXTRA := NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Database search the table- "admin_user" here you can add Admin Username and Password manually by clicking Insert link or you can add by MySQL query- UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE `username` = 'ADMINUSERNAME'; .
If you forgot the Database name, find from here- /app/etc/local.xml and open the code then search DB here (e.g-  )

Comment: ** eg.- <dbname><![CDATA[user_magedatabase]]></dbname>

Comment: thank you. in my case, haven't any username in database. i try run Jzet's script and it worded. Hehe

Answer (score 0):

**To create magento admin user follow steps**

1. **first step (query)**

> ```
> INSERT INTO admin_user
> SELECT NULL user_id,
> "firstname" firstname,
> "lastname" ,
> "example@example.com" email,
> "scommerce.mage" username,
> "8f1d735b076352461bf8064f0953822e:sc" PASSWORD,
> NOW( ) created,
> NULL modified,
> NULL logdate,
> 0 lognum,
> 0 reload_acl_flag,
> 1 is_active,
> (SELECT MAX(extra) FROM admin_user WHERE extra IS NOT NULL) extra,
> NULL rp_token,
> NOW() rp_token_created_at,
> NULL failures_num,
> NULL first_failure,
> NULL lock_expires;
> ```

**2. second step (query)**

> ```
> INSERT INTO admin_role SELECT NULL role_id,
> 1 parent_id,
> 2 tree_level,
> 0 sort_order,
> 'U' role_type,
> (SELECT user_id FROM admin_user WHERE username = 'admin') user_id,
> 'Administrators' role_name,
> 1 gws_is_all,
> NULL gws_websites,
> NULL gws_store_groups;
> ```

And then reset password through MD5 format in my your database.